# Numerical Algorithms to compute common bases for symmetric commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a set of symmetric matrices $A_1,\dots,A_k \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ which commute with each other. This implies that they have a common eigenbasis. What are the best algorithms to find this bases given $A_1,\dots,A_k$? Ideally, these should be numerically stable.

Comment: I wonder if knowing all $k$ commuting matrices can provide a better algorithm than what's known for finding the eigenbasis for a single matrix.

Comment: Exploiting the commuting matrices for computing a common eigenbasis depends on the structure of eigenvalue multiplicity.  At one extreme we have a random real symmetric matrix $S$ commuting with the identity $I$, and the latter matrix does not help find the eigenbasis of $S$.  On the other hand $A_1$ and $A_2$ might each have repeated eigenvalues while $A_1 A_2$ has all eigenvalues distinct.  Then the product would (up to normalization) determine the common eigenbasis.